# Filter search results based on data of a relationship in a model

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, relationships

In this scenario, I have **Patients Model** and **Reports Model**. where Patients hasMany Reports.

```
<?php

namespace App;  
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use DB;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;

class Patient extends Authenticatable
{
    public function reports()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Reports');
    }
}
```

In a view, I have a list of all patients with their report ids against them. We have a search patient module where we can search Patient with **Patient id** and **Report id**. I am able to satisfy search for **Patient id** using

$data = Patient::where("id", "LIKE", "%{$search_patient}%")

But could not solve the scenario to search patient and filter results based on **Report id**, as the data of reports is being retrieved using a hasMany relationship

The below is the result, where Patient data is coming from Patient model and Reports data is coming from Reports model using hasMany relationships. My requirement is when I search with Report id, I should be able to see only data with that report id and user info againt that.

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "group_id": 1000,
    "date": "01-01-14",
    "name": "Voss",
    "address": "My Home 1",
    "reports": [
      {
        "id": "ABC123",
        "name": "Report1"
      },
      {
        "id": "EDC123",
        "name": "Report2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "group_id": 1000,
    "date": "01-01-15",
    "name": "Rosalia",
    "address": "My Home 2",
    "reports": [
      {
        "id": "RTC123",
        "name": "Report3"
      },
      {
        "id": "TYH123",
        "name": "Report4"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Does a Report belongs to a patient? in that case you have to define a belongsTo relationship instead of hasMany. And what error do you get when trying to retrieve reports from a patient?

Comment: each patient has multiple reports. I am displaying the list of patients and report ids against each record. Now how can I search patients based on report id. Can u read the question again once.

Comment: no, i get the question but you have not shown the Report model with patient relationship..If i read your question, i would think that a report can have multiple patients, which seems unlikely. Thats why i am trying to determine what your report-patient relationship should be.

Comment: Ok... my each report is associated with a single user. Do u have any comments on the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a belongsTo relationship to your Report model like this:

```
public function patient() {
    return $this->belongsTo("App\Models\Patient", "patient_id", "id");
}
```

Then perform your search in your Report model

```
$data = Report::with('patient')->where('id', $report_id)->get();
```

The result should look like this

```
...
{
  "id": ABC123,
  "name": Report 1,
  "patient": {
    "id": 2,
    "group_id": 1000,
    "date": "01-01-15",
    "name": "Rosalia",
    "address": "My Home 2",
  }
},
...
```

*Edit*:
If you insist to use your patient as base then do this:

```
 Patient::whereHas('reports', function ($query) use($report_id) {
     $query->where('id', $report_id);
 })->with(['reports' => function ($query) use($report_id) {
     $query->where('id', $report_id);
 }])->get();
```

1. whereHas will perform the search
2. with will eager load only the report id you specified

Comment: I need patient information as parent and report as children. each patient has multiple reports. I am displaying the list of patients and report ids against each record. Now how can I search patients based on report id. Can u read the question again once.

Comment: I've edited my answer based on what you need. See changes below.

Answer (score 0):

First add a belongsTo in your Report Model:

```
public function patient()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Patient::class);
}
```

Then retrieve it like this:

```
$reportId = "ABC123"; //for demo purposses, you get this dynamically

$record = Report::where('record_id', '=', $reportId)->first();
    // i used record_id, but you probably have just id;

$patient = $record->patient()->with('records')->first();

dd($patient);
```

result is this:

```
Patient {#199 ▼
  #guarded: []
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:5 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "group_id" => 1000
    "date": "01-01-15"
    "name" => "Rosalia"
    "created_at" => null
    "updated_at" => null
  ]
  #original: array:5 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: array:1 [▼
    "reports" => Collection {#204 ▼
      #items: array:2 [▼
        0 => Report {#207 ▶}
        1 => Report {#209 ▶}
      ]
    }
  ]
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #fillable: []
```